# JasperReports (iReport) Chart Define X Axis Tickcount

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jfreechart

Find a screen from my report attached.

It is an AreaChart with a category dataset in a multiple axis chart.

The Y Axis is well formed.
The X Axis is not.
The X Axis is based on a Timestamp field.
Can I configure the TickCount in iReport?
The X Axis has to be exploded like Y axis.

I´m working with actual iReport and don´t have permission to use Java.

thx and Best regards

Christian

[image: x/y Axis Labels]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes, un-checking and re-checking the tick-mark buttons in the chart's properties window will work..

Comment: Also in this case **grrrrrr**

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure if it is a bug or not but I spent WAY too long myself trying to figure out the same problem.